# FirebaseAuth Cannot resolve method 'setCustomUserClaims(java.lang.String, java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>)' error , How to solve to?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

[I am doing in this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QsmN.png) but it's give me error like  `Cannot resolve method 'setCustomUserClaims(java.lang.String, java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>)'`

I just want to set a custom claim that this user is admin, to use security rule like

```
"Posts": {
     ".read": "auth != null",
     ".write": "auth.token.admin== true " // only admins can write to it
```

i have put this code after Phone Authentication is successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting custom claims is a function of the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin) (for backends), using its [features to manage users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users), not the Firebase auth web client SDK (for frontends).  They are different tools for different jobs, even though they are both available for JavaScript.

If you want to set custom claims, you will have to do that with the admin SDK on a backend you control.

Comment: So i can't use custom claims in android with java?

Comment: The Firebase Admin SDK is available for java as well as several other languages.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58373338/can-i-use-this-claim-in-firebase-database-security-rules here i have do what you suggest please check it