# Can i use this claim in firebase database security rules?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have use this firebase to set a custom claim

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sellerCustomClaim = functions.database.ref('/Users/{userNumber}')
.onCreate((data, context) => {
    const sellerNumber = context.params.userNumber;
    const uid = context.auth.uid;
    const customClaims = {
      number: sellerNumber,
    };

    console.log(`Uid: ${uid}, number: ${sellerNumber}`);

    console.log(`before Seller number: ${sellerNumber}`);
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, customClaims).then(() => {
        console.log(`claim added!`);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
});
```

Here i am set user number as a claim object (or what it's called i don't know) when a new user account is create in this `/Users/userNumber` database location.

Log is `claim added!` but i am not sure that claim is added or not.

And if added would i able to use database security rules like

```
Posts": {
     ".read": "auth != null",
     ".write": "auth.token.number == "123456789" // "123456789" is some numebr
```

Comment: "Ii am not sure that claim is added or not." Why aren't you sure? What makes you doubt that it was added? If it is because your rules don't pick up the new claim yet, keep in mind that it may take up to an hour before the claim shows up in security rules (since the ID token that the client uses is valid for an hour from the moment is minted).

Comment: thanks i got it , so is this is `auth.token.number` write way to get that claim in security rules?

Comment: Yup, seems to be: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#authtoken